# `bytes.fromhex` and `to_bytes` method in Raku?

Tags: byte, raku

I have a Python3 function that combine two `bytes`, one use [bytes.fromhex()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fromhex#bytes.fromhex) method, and the other use [to_bytes()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=to_bytes#int.to_bytes) method:

```
from datatime import datetime

def bytes_add() -> bytes:
  bytes_a = bytes.fromhex('6812')
  bytes_b = datetime.now().month.to_bytes(1, byteorder='little', signed=False)
  return bytes_a + bytes_b
```

Is it possible to write a same function as above in Raku?(if so, How to control `byteorder` and `signed` params?)

as for `byteorder`, say convert number `1024` to `bytes` in Python:

```
(1024).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little') # Output: b'\x00\x04', byte 00 is before byte 04
```

as a contrast, convert number `1024` to `Buf` or `Blob` in Raku:

```
buf16.new(1024) # Output: Buf[uint16]:0x<0400>, byte 00 is after byte 04
```

is there any way to get `Buf[uint16]:0x<0004>` in the above example in Raku?

**Update**:

inspired by **codesections**, I try to figure out a solution similar to **codesections**'s answer:

```
sub bytes_add() {
    my $bytes_a = pack("H*", '6812');
    my $bytes_b = buf16.new(DateTime.now.month);
    $bytes_a ~ $bytes_b;
}
```

But still don't know how to use `byteorder`.

Comment: https://docs.raku.org/routine/read-int16 ?

Comment: probably not, `read-int16` return `int` instead of `bytes`/`Buf`.

Comment: https://docs.raku.org/routine/subbuf then?

Comment: may be Buf or Blob, don't know how to pass `byteorder` if it exist in Raku.

Comment: At Buf/Blob level, there is no byte order?  Byte order is only applicable to its elements, and Buf/Blob is agnostic to that. Only if you try to interprete the Buf/Blob elements, does byte order matter.  And in the case of integers, there's read-int's and read-bits family of methods.

Comment: `buf16.new(1024)` is close to `(1024).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')` in Python, except the byte order. I tried `reverse`, `read-int`'s and `read-bits` methods, but  fails to get `Buf[uint16]:0x<0004>` instead.

Comment: `pack("S*", 1024)`  output `Buf:0x<00 04>`, maybe what i need. thanks everyone~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a same function as above in Raku?

Yes.  I'm not 100% sure I understand the overall *goal* of the function you provided, but a literal/line-by-line translation is certainly possible.  If you would like to elaborate on the goal, it may also be possible to achieve the same goal in an easier/more idiomatic way.

Here's the line-by-line translation:

```
sub bytes-add(--> Blob) {
    my $bytes-a = Blob(<68 12>);
    my $bytes-b = Blob(DateTime.now.month);
    Blob(|$bytes-a, |$bytes-b)
}
```

The output of `bytes-add` is printed by default using its hexadecimal representation (`Blob:0x<44 0C 09>`).  If you'd like to print it more like Python prints its byte literals, you can do so with `bytes-add».chr.raku`, which prints as `("D", "\x[C]", "\t")`.

> if so, How to control `byteorder`?

Because the code above constructs the `Blob` from a `List`, you can simply `.reverse` the list to use the opposite order.

Comment: Blob is immutable, is it possible to use `Buf`, eg:  `my $init-buffer = Buf.new(); $init-buffer.append($bytes)`?